# Rhino Mocks and Visual Studio: How do I fix this error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rhino-mocks, rhino, rhino-mocks-3.5

I'm having another fun problem with Rhino Mocks. Can anyone answer this one:

Here's the call that I'm making in my code:

```
Expect.On(this.mockDal).Call(this.mockDal.SaveObject(entry)).IgnoreArguments();
```

mockDal is mocking something of type Dal, and it's SaveObject method's signature is this;

```
void SaveObject(object obj);
```

Visual Studio, on the first part of my code (i.e. not the part with IgnoreArguments) is giving me this wonderfully confusing error:

`Error 1   The type arguments for method 'Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces.ICreateMethodExpectation.Call<T>(T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

I've tried this with entry being of type var and its actual type (called SpaceViewEntry), and it gives me the same error each time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set up an expectation that the SaveObject will be called, using the new AAA syntax might be easier:

```
this.mockDal.Expect(m => m.SaveObject(entry)).IgnoreArguments();
```

Comment: Not sure.  I learned Rhino.Mocks using the AAA syntax (and the extension methods).  I don't really know how they translate to the Expect.* and Stub.* method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this

```
Expect.On(this.mockDal).Call(this.mockDal.SaveObject((object)entry)).IgnoreArguments();
```